# How to redirect with the same locale in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to make a redirection with a locale included:

```
 get '/login', to: redirect('/:locale/newlogin', status: 301)
```

that if input `mysite.com/en/login` redirects to `mysite.com/:locale/newlogin`  how can I do it so it gets redirected to the locale `mysite.com/en/newlogin` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, define correctly routes.rb:

```
scope "/:locale" do
  get '/login', to: redirect("/newlogin", status: 302)
end
```

Second, somewhere in your ApplicationController must be locale setting:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end
end
```

Read [Setting the Locale from URL Params](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-url-params) and [I18n for Rails](https://dev.to/morinoko/setting-up-i18n-for-rails-with-locales-from-url-params-38pg).